# Test non-idempotent web methods with Pester

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-3.0, pester

I'm attempting to test a PowerShell command (`Set-PropertyValue`) that sets a property value of a SharePoint list item.  The function use the `Invoke-WebMethod` function do to the actual work.

My current `Set-PropertyValue.Test.ps1` file:

```
# include stuff omitted

Describe 'Set-PropertyValue' {

  #
  # arrange
  #

  # set $url, $list, $id, $property variables
  ...

  # the value that it should be 
  $expected=10.5

  BeforeEach {
    # get the property's current value
    $original = Get-PropertyValue $url $list $id $property
  }

  AfterEach {
    # restore original value
    Set-PropertyValue $url $list $id $property $original
  }

  It "Should set a property's value" {

    #
    # act
    #

    # update property's value
    $response = Set-PropertyValue $url $list $id $property $expected

    # get the new value
    $actual = Get-PropertyValue $url $list $id $property

    #
    # assert
    #

    $response.statuscode | should be 204 # no content
    $actual | Should Be $expected

  } # It

} # Describe
```

I don't like this for a number of reasons:

- external dependence upon `Get-PropertyValue`
- no test isolation; changes are made to SharePoint list
- potential to level list item in undesirable state
- test not structured to test multiple properties easily, in a loop perhaps

Is there a better way to test this?

Comment: I don't have a solution for you, but I've been struggling with the same things. [I found this article to be a good read](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/why-tdd-for-powershell-or-why-pester-or-why-unit-test-scripting-language).

Comment: The more I think about this situation, the more I think that these are really integration tests.

Comment: Yeah exactly. Personally, I'm struggling with whether Pester is still the appropriate tool to run integration tests, and how to implement them effectively. If you find that you've worked this out, I'd love to hear your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

- place all command scripts in a subdirectory (e.g `Functions`)
- create a module file (e.g. `PsFoo.psm1`); 'dot-source' each of the command's script files (e.g. `Functions\Invoke-Foo.ps1`), but exclude the unit-test file (e.g. `Functions\Invoke-Foo.Tests.ps1`).
- create a module test file (e.g. `PsFoo.Tests.ps1`) that 'dot-sources' the module file and contains all of the integration tests.
- refactor all unit tests that exercise more than one command (like my question's example) into an integration test
- `PS> Invoke-Pester` will run the integration tests (in `PsFoo.Tests.ps1`) and the unit tests (in `Functions\*.Tests.ps1`).